# Node.js/Express error: cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have some code (app.js, in the server)

```
console.log("Server started. If you're reading this then your computer is still alive."); //Unnecessary test command to make sure everything works.

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = require("http").Server(app);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client");
});

app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

serv.listen(2000);

//Set up server stuff. This isn't touched.

var io = require("socket.io")(serv, {});
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Socket connection"); //This will print to the server, not the developer console in your browser.
});

//Initialize sockets and set up socket listeners. This isn't touched either, except when adding new events.
```

And some more code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiplayer!</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My folder structure is:

```
multiplayer_game  
 app.js  
 package.json  
 node_modules (folder)  
  node stuff  
 client (folder)  
  index.html  
  js (folder)  
  img (folder)  
 server (folder)
```

Where the farther in the file is, the more "nested" it is.
When I open the page by doing `node app.js` (folder already cd'ed) and go to `localhost:2000`, I get "Cannot GET /". When I go to `localhost:2000/client`, I get everything fine. What can I do to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a router for that.

```
const router = express.Router;
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client");
});
app.use('/', router);
```

A middleware is not capable to handle various http methods.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! If you can, could you explain what this "router" is?

Comment: @Someone'sAlt Router is just a simple middleware shipped with Express that knows how to handle routes and http messages.

Comment: When I run it the `app.use("/", router)` part makes my server lag out when loading through localhost:2000. I posted a question on this